# Move Vertical annotation only across datapoints

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I have a chart with many datapoints and a vertical annotation. I want the vertical annotation to be moved only from datapoint to datapoint and not between them.

I have written this in order to set the Vertical annotation :

```
 VA.X = chart1.Series[0].Points[0].XValue;
            VA.AllowMoving = true;
            VA.IsInfinitive = true;
            VA.AnchorDataPoint = chart1.Series[0].Points[0];              
            VA.LineColor = Color.Red;
            VA.LineWidth = 2;
            VA.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;
```

and this is how the Vertical annotation gets its values

```
 private void chart1_AnnotationPositionChanging(object sender, AnnotationPositionChangingEventArgs e)
{
         
   var pt1 = (int)VA.X;
    int i = 0;

        foreach (var signal in Signals)
        {
            valtot = signal.Points[pt1].YValues[0];
                               
            i++;
        }
```

How could I just move from one datapoint to another? I don't want the values between the datapoints and therefore the VA should not be able to be placed only on datapoints.

EDIT :
Here is a picture of what I want to achieve.

[image]

the little blue circles represent datapoints. I want my red line to move only across these little blue circles and not in the area between them.